# Facebook Messenger Chatbot - How can a user post to timeline with a button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've created a chatbot on FB Messenger. At some point, the bot responds with e.g. some image. Below the image, I've managed to create a button so the user can 'share' the image to his/her FB Messenger friends.

Is there a way to create a button so the user can post this image to his timeline?

I can't find something on [FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/message-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [blog post](https://blog.chatbot.com/messenger-share-button-on-steroids-share-anything-from-messenger-bot-to-newsfeed-6234e5ee9a34), use this template for the url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<APP_ID>&link=<ENCODED-URL-TO SHARE>&picture=<IMAGE_URL>&name=<TITLE>&caption=<CAPTION>&description=<DESCRIPTION>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT URI>
```